# Django and HTMX I am looking for not "hacky" way to update class of link that calls HTMX request. Like "refresh-self" or something along those lines

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-templates, htmx

I have a problem with HTMX in Django. I basically have two important components on page. List of categories and content that is being shown after you click on category.

I was working nicely with just standard htmx "out of the box". But I started having problems when I wanted to add `active` css class on category link after you click it (to show user where he is currently).

I did a lot of experiments with `hx-swap-oob` and `hx-swap` but the only thing that work was this:

(it is the most relevant part of the code)

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body" hx-boost="true" hx-target="#manual_results">
            <div id="manual_categories">
                {% include 'partials/manual_categories.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="manual_results">
        {% include 'partials/manual_entries_list.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

and in `manual_entries_list.html`:

```
<some html results>
        <div id="manual_categories" hx-swap-oob="true">
            {% include 'partials/manual_categories.html' %}
        </div>
```

Each category has simple if statement in django template code that is checking if it is selected (based on url path.)

And it is working, thing is, on the first request the categories are rendered twice (which is logical since I have 2 includes on the same HTML). After I select one category, everything goes back to normal because HTMX "starts to understand what is happening" and it switches the categories from `manual_entries_list.html` into our main page.

And like I said it works, I modified `manual_entries_list.html` to:

```
    <some html results>
    <div class="set_size_to_0px">
        <div id="manual_categories" hx-swap-oob="true">
            {% include 'partials/manual_categories.html' %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

So it is always invisible (so I will have only one set of categories visible).

The thing is, that it is an obvious hack. I am sure that there needs to be a better way of solving this problem but I cannot find it.

(I even tried to do it with plain javascript the thing is that categories are rendered in a for loop so it is pretty much impossible to get IDs correctly etc.)

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid this issue is to detect the HTMX request in the view function, pass this state to your templates and render HTMX content only if needed. HTMX will add a [HX-Request: true](https://htmx.org/docs/#requests) header to each request.

For the detection you can use the [Django-HTMX](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx) package that provides a [`request.htmx` variable](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx/blob/main/src/django_htmx/middleware.py) in your view functions that will be `True` if the request is coming from HTMX. Or if you want to check it manually:

```
def my_view(request):
    is_htmx = request.headers.get('HX-Request') == 'true'
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'is_htmx': is_htmx})
```

After that in `manual_entries_list.html` template include HTMX related stuff only in the HTMX requests:

```
<some html results>
{% if is_htmx %}
<div id="manual_categories" hx-swap-oob="true">
  {% include 'partials/manual_categories.html' %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick. I still feels a little bit "hacky" but I think that it is also because of HTMX characteristic in general. But it definitely works!

Comment: I agree, it feels a little bit strange to use HTMX at first because previously we never had to deal with request headers. However, with HTMX request/response headers are the standard place to pass such meta-data. Otherwise we would have to embed them into HTML content, e.g `<div data-is-htmx="true"></div>` and parse it. Using headers is just a cleaner way. The `HX-Request` is also useful if you want to serve 'normal' and HTMX content on the same path. You just check the request header and construct the partial or full page content accordingly.